# Add New attribute with default value in Rapidminer

Tags: data-mining, data-warehouse, rapidminer

I am very new to this tool "Rapid miner".What i want to know is how to add a new attribute to one data set with default value in rapid-miner. I tried with using "Generate attributes" but how to set a default value to the new attribute. Do i have to use "Generate Empty Attribute" ??
There are two data set in my process and one of them have a additional attribute called "other".I want to get the union of both sets. do i have to use the append operator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Generate Attributes` operator is the right one to create new attributes. The value of the new attribute for each example can be generated from other attributes in the same example as well as from constant values (which is probably what you mean by default value) that you enter directly or from the values of macros. There are also functions that can be used.

The `Join` operator or possibly `Union` is likely to be the one you need to create a new example set with attributes from both inputs. The `Append` operator is used to add more examples whilst keeping the attributes the same.

Comment: Thak you very much for the help.. !!